# Send image to server through httpmultipart

Tags: android, image

I am making an android app in which i am sending images from gallery to server through xml..Any type of help will be appreciated...  hanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I handle it in my application:

```
// bitmap is your Bitmap object
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// The next line should be adjust to use the format and compression you want.
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);           
byte[] byteArr = stream.toByteArray();
// The next line would be where you write the byte array to your xml structure:
myXml += Base64.encodeBase64String( byteArr );
```

In my application, the byte[] gets saved to the db as a blob prior to the xml structure being created.  So this code isn't exactly what I'm doing.  But it should give you the idea.

Comment: but when i am checking through serverside it is showing broken file

Comment: You have to do things on the server side to unencode it and create the image from the byte array.  Are you doing those things server side?

Comment: Also of note, I'm using the Apache Commons Codec which includes the Base64 codec, which can be found here:  http://commons.apache.org/codec/

Comment: Actully my file is getting store /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20110922_124932.jpg and i want to send this image as multipart entry...So Can you give me some idea about this ...